# SSRS HTTP reports URL redirect to HTTPS

Tags: iis, reporting-services

I have been trying to redirect my **SSRS's URL from HTTP URL to HTTPS.** E.g(`http://ServeName/Reports` to `https://ServeName/Reports`).

Using this [example](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/), the **IIS's URL rewrite's** rule only redirect the **ServerName** `http://ServerName` to `https://ServerName`.

[image]

Reading through internet I have seen that SSRS's **80 -TCP port** is not running on IIS.

Any configuration to edit?

BTW, I am using **SSRS 2019** and **IIS 10**

Comment: I cannot understand what do you mean about the issue. But you can enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to check the process of url rewrite. Then you can find out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved this after changing some configurations.**

**Reporting Services Configuration manager:**

Web Portal URL:

1. Removing the access on port 80 for both web portal
2. Add **(All IPv4)** and **(All IPv6)** for HTTPS port 443 on both web portal

**Note:** After removing the access of port 80 you are allowing that port 443 will be handle by IIS. Because the port 80 is handle by SSRS's native mode.

[image]

**On IIS:**

On the URL Rewrite's rule:

1. Redirect URL: `https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}`
2. Unchecked the Appended query string box.
   **Note:** By unchecking that box you are allowing to append everything after the **/**-mark. E.g. (`https://Servername/.../...`)

[image]