# redirect HTTP to HTTPS in SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, iis-10

As described in this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69392311/ssrs-http-reports-url-redirect-to-https/71238567#71238567), I removed the HTTP binding on port 80 and added the URL Rewrite, but it's not working. I get Service Unavailable in browser when I load HTTP. In IIS, is the URL Rewrite on the server level? or a site level?

Comment: You can use failed request tracing to check the rewrite process, check why the service unavailable and what the rewritten url is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: To test a FRT, I removed the HTTP binding on port 80 (in SSRS Configuration) to get the 503 error. Then, when I enable and add a failed request trace in IIS on my "default web site" for 503 errors, no tracing log is created. I'm not sure how SSRS triggers a trace in IIS. Any thoughts?

Comment: 503 maybe caused by application pool stop. Please check application pool status make sure it is running.